# Magento 2 catalog category link widget is not working

Tags: magento2, category, catalog

I wanted to insert catalog category in my content, however, it keeps showing a broken image whenever I try to use it. I have also tried manually coding it. Does anyone know the fix for this?[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Hide editor
2. Delete whole content
3. Add widget and save

Comment: These procedures didn't work. Please let me know if there's another fix :)

Comment: Do you have any js error??

Comment: None, no errors show up whenever i try to insert the widget.

Comment: Check web console for any js error also check log files.

Comment: I got:
JQMIGRATE: Logging is active                   jquery-migrate.js:21 
and
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'autocomplete' of undefined       
authentication-popup.js:25

Comment: First try to solve this js error!

Comment: Broken image aside, does it work on frontend. WYSIWYG editor might not render this element correctly which does not mean it won't work on frontend where it is rendered by php code.